# How to Split a delimiter string and store it as array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have my json similar to this :

```
{"Details": {
  "id": "1423",
  "StudentName": "xxxx",
  "Joineddate" : "yyy",
  "Personalinfo" : yyyy,ZZZZ,(xxx|pppp),rrrr

}}
```

I want to store it as array similar to this

```
[0] -->  yyyy
[1] -->  ZZZZ
[2]
    [0] ---> xxx
    [1] ---> pppp
[3]  --> rrrr
```

When it is only one delimiter i.e comma(,), I can achieve it using the following code :

```
List = input.split(",")
lst = []
for var in List:
    lst.append(var)
    l_dict = json.loads(json.dumps(lst))
```

But I don't know how to achieve that?

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: You've given us an ambiguous example and a code fragment that makes no sense. There isn't much to go on here.

Comment: Its not a complex json structure. @tdelaney

Comment: It would be easier to parse if it was - you'd just send it to the JSON parser. Even enforcing valid Python syntax, like `"'yyyy','ZZZZ',('xxx','pppp'),'rrrr'"` would be fine, as you could send that to `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: You've substantively changed the question. Answers that worked for the previous version may not work for the current version, and vice versa. Instead of doing that, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While my answer is for this input `123,456,(753,862),487` version of the question now it seems there is an edit and is being reverted to the original.

This can may be get you a structure as you wanted

```
>>> map(lambda x : float(x) if "(" not in x else map(float,x.strip("()").split(",")) ,re.findall("(\d+\.\d+|\(\d+,\d+\)|\(\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+\)|\d+)","123.123,456,(753,862),(123.2,234.5),487"))
[123.123, 456.0, [753.0, 862.0], [123.2, 234.5], 487.0]
```

Else you can simply use

```
import ast
lst=list(ast.literal_eval("123,456,(753,862),487"))
```

You would get a structure like this.

```
[0] -->  123
[1] -->  456
[2]
[3]  [0] ---> 753
[3]  [1] ---> 862
[4]  --> 487
```

Comment: Note that this won't work for the given sample input, which has strings that aren't enclosed by quotes. `ast.literal_eval()` won't work for that.

Comment: Not only that, but your first method is hard-coded to only work on numbers - and only integers, at that. What do you think the chances are of "personal info" being a bunch of integers?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 . I did not understand what you are trying to say. If the sample input is this `"123,456,(753,862),487"` then `lst=list(ast.literal_eval("123,456,(753,862),487"))` works.

Comment: But that isn't the given sample input in the question. You're answering a question different from the one asked - an easier one.

Comment: Looks like the question was heavily edited. Your answer would work for the new version but not the old one - however, there's an existing answer that would work for the old version but not the new one. As these kinds of edits negate the value of a question, I've rolled it back to the original version. If the OP asks a new question that would be a good fit for this answer, I encourage you to post this answer on that new question.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 So I hadn't seen the earlier versions. It sucks to even attempt to answer a question on SO if you work on something and find out it is now again reverted back to an old version.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you only have one level of nesting and the pattern matches exactly you can use

```
lst = map(lambda x: x[1:-1].split('|') if x[0] == '(' and x[-1] == ')' else x, input.split(','))
```

It essentially takes the first `split`'s array as input and looks for the parentheses and `split`s again by `|`

Comment: We can't conclude that the braces will appear in particular position. It may come anywhere

Comment: By "braces" do you mean parentheses or are there more types? Are there many sets of parens? Can they nest?

Comment: Then I suggest you go with TigerhawkT3's suggesttion

Comment: Braces is parentheses. Only one type of parentheses occur actually @tdelaney